# String compare w/ if statement

Tags: java, android, authentication, base64

I am trying to compare a string from EditText fields to strings in shared preferences. If the strings match a new activity starts. The string in Sharedpreferenced is encoded with Base64. I am trying to compare the edit text string to the sharedpreferences string after it has been decoded but am unable to get the coding correct. how can I code this properly. examples are appreciated. my comparator is on line 77 and 78

```
 44. public void onClick(View arg0) {
 45.    
 46.   sp=this.getSharedPreferences("AccessApp", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
 47.  
 48.   
 49.   
 50.   
 51.   byte[] key = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
 52.   
 53.   
 54.   try {
 55.    user = sp.getString("USERNAME_KEY", null);
 56.        String decryptedUser = decrypt(user, key);  
 57.        
 58.         
 59.   }
 60.  catch (Exception e) {
 61.   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 62.   e.printStackTrace();
 63.  }   
 64.  try {
 65.       pass = sp.getString("PASSWORD_KEY", null);
 66.       String decryptedPass = decrypt(pass, key);  
 67.       
 68.        
 69.
 70. } catch (Exception e) {
 71.   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 72.   e.printStackTrace();
 73. }
 74.  
 75.  if(lBttn.equals(arg0)){
 76.    
 77.     if((uname.getText().toString().equals(decryptedUser))  && 
 78.       (pword.getText().toString().equals(decryptedPass)))
 79.      
 80.           {
 81.         Toast.makeText(this, "You are Logged In", 20000).show();
 82.                
 83.              Intent intent;
 84.               intent=new Intent(this,details.class);
 85.               startActivity(intent);
 86.             flag=1;
 87.           }
```

Comment: What about spicing your code with some Log.d()  displaying where you are and what your strings actually are? Usuallz this helps ti understand what's going on

Comment: What is this statement "if(lBttn.equals(arg0))"?
And what's the problem in your result? I think if condition is ok. Does it resturn false results?

Comment: As well as anything else, *please* sort out your exception handling. Just dumping a stack trace and then continuing as if everything is fine is almost *never* the right thing to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 copies of `decryptedUser`  and `decryptedPass` each. One pair inside the try blocks and another pair as members. They are always empty at line 77 because you assign the decrypted values to different variables (lines 56 and 66) that you never use.  Move the whole code into a single try block.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    ...
    ...
    String decryptedUser;
    String decryptedPass;
    try {
        user = sp.getString("USERNAME_KEY", null);
        decryptedUser = decrypt(user, key);  
        pass = sp.getString("PASSWORD_KEY", null);
        decryptedPass = decrypt(pass, key);
        /* Your if statements follow from here */
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. cant believe I overlooked that. simply amazing.